# C# ASP.NET MVC Use of Azure Key Vault Runtime Initialized Variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-keyvault

I am looking for the most appropriate way to store and/or use variables initialized during startup (Program.cs) throughout the application as needed, or an acceptable alternative process if there's a better way to accomplish this.

I.e., the following code snippet in Program.cs initializes the Azure Key Vault connectionString variable at runtime with a correct value retrieved from the designated Azure Key Vault:

```
var keyVaultUrl = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("KeyVault:KeyVaultUrl");

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();    

    SecretClientOptions options = new SecretClientOptions()
    {
        Retry =
        {
            Delay= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
            MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16),
            MaxRetries = 5,
            Mode = RetryMode.Exponential
         }
    };    

    var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), new DefaultAzureCredential(), options);

    KeyVaultSecret secretConnectionString = client.GetSecret("ConnectionString");

    string connectionString = secretConnectionString.Value;

}
```

The objective is to use this variable or others on-demand without having to call the code another time.  Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Shove it all into an immutable object registered as a Singleton-scoped DI service.

Comment: Depending on your use case, what if your secret value has changed, do you want to restart your service? I would recommend wrapping the Secret Client into your own service class but still calling the same code, in this way, you can always get the latest value from the KV. In addition, the ClientSecret caches the value for 1 hour by default. You can change this behaviour based on this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-net/azure-key-vault-proxy/

Comment: @CharlesHan Reaching-out to the KeyVault on _every_ access is a bad idea.

Comment: That's why the ClinetSercret has caching built into it. I am not suggesting you should reach out the KV every time, but you need a balance for getting the key without restarting your services (if downtime is not an issue, do so.) @Dai

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Downtime isn't an issue for my scheduling purposes.  I'll look into each suggestion.

Comment: Save the `KeyVault` variables in Azure App Settings as `Key - MYconn
Value - @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=Uri)`.

Comment: Instead of getting the variable from `KeyVault`, set the keyvault variable in `Azure App Service` => `Application Settings`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps to store the `KeyVault` Connection string in Azure Appsettings.

I do agree with @Dai, yes instead of getting the `ConnectionString/Varaibles` from  `KeyVault` , we can store the values in `Azure App Service` => `Configuration`  => `Application Settings`.

***My appsettings.json***

```cs
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyVal": "DummyString"
  }
```

- Create a secret in `KeyVault` and copy the Secret Identifier.

[image]

***Azure App Settings***

[image]

[image]

Thanks to @[Jayant Kulkarni](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/simple-configuration-of-connection-string-through-key-vault2/) - reference taken from c-sharpcorner.